# Aws ecs fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to transform this app app which open a url with firefox inside docker and push to rtmp with ffmpeg basically. https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-live-events .
Used same dockerfile and made a docker compose for fargate deploy.

My question is **how can I use multiple fargate tasks can work seperatly**. I will start those task from lambda with different parameters.  I don't want same task with same parameter scaled.
Where is this indepent working style should be configured? ECS? Fargate?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by working separately? You want to have different services for your tasks?

Comment: I meant same docker image with different enviroment variables

Answer (score 2):

You would use [ContainerOverride](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverride.html) to specify different environment variables for each task.

However, if you are just trying to pass a different URL to each task, I would recommend pushing URLs to an SQS queue, configuring your tasks to pull from that queue and run it as an ECS service, and finally configure autoscaling of the service based on the queue depth.